# Multiple imports from Slack to Mattermost duplicates posts

Tags: import, slack, mattermost

When you export your history from Slack you get a .zip file. You can import this into Mattermost to aid your move from one to the other.

My problem is because we haven't paid for Slack I can't export our history in one go. I have an old .zip file containing our Slack history from the previous few years and I can generate a new one for the latest history. But if I import the old one followed by the new one any posts that exist in both are duplicated.

Is there some way of handling this in Mattermost? Can I merge the .zip files before I do the import? Or do we just have to live with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Mattermost doesn't have any way of handling the duplicate posts at the moment.

If you don't mind writing a script though, this can be fixed relatively easily - you would just need to work through every row in the `Posts` table of your Mattermost database, and check if there are any other rows with exact same `UserId`, `ChannelId`, `CreateAt` and `Message` fields, and if so, delete those rows.

Comment: Is there any reason why this can't be implemented on the import, or has it just not been done yet?

Comment: No technical reason. It just hasn't been done yet.

Long term, I believe the plan is to switch to using the new Mattermost Bulk Import interface, and an external ETL tool to transform Slack export data into the format that interface expects. The Bulk Import interface already performs this deduplication.